# org.specs2.mock.Mockito matchers are not working as expected

Tags: scala, mockito, specifications, specs2

Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
import org.specs2.mock.Mockito
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import org.specs2.specification.Scope
import akka.event.LoggingAdapter

class MySpec extends Specification with Mockito {


  "Something" should {
      "do something" in new Scope {

      val logger = mock[LoggingAdapter]

      val myVar = new MyClassTakingLogger(logger)

      myVar.doSth()

      there was no(logger).error(any[Exception], "my err msg")
      }
  }

}
```

When running this, I get the following error:

```
[error]    org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:
[error]    Invalid use of argument matchers!
[error]    2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
[error]    -> at         org.specs2.mock.mockito.MockitoMatchers$class.any(MockitoMatchers.scala:47)
[error]
[error]    This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
[error]        //incorrect:
[error]        someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
[error]    When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
[error]    For example:
[error]        //correct:
[error]        someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
```

Which would make a lot of sense, but neither `eq("my err msg")` nor `equals("my err msg")` does the job as I get an error. What am I missing?

Comment: `eq("my err msg")` is required for this case, and I suspect the error you're getting when using it is a different error—possibly related to your actual test. Can you please paste in the error you get when using `eq`?

Comment: It is a very vague compilation error:

     `[error]   (template: String,arg1: Any)Unit <and>
     [error]   (cause: Throwable,message: String)Unit
     [error]  cannot be applied to (Exception, Boolean)
     [error]       there was no(logger).error(any[Exception], eq("my err msg"))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are using matchers to match parameters you have to use them for *all* parameters. as the `all arguments have to be provided by matchers` indicates.

Moreover if you use a `specs2` matcher it needs to be strongly-typed. `equals` is a `Matcher[Any]` but there is no conversion from `Matcher[Any]` to a `String` which is what `method` accepts.

So you need a `Matcher[T]` or a `Matcher[String]` in your case. If you just want to test for equality, the strongly-typed matcher is `===`

```
there was no(logger).error(any[Exception], ===("hey"))
```

Comment: How would you create an arbitrary `Matcher[String]`?

Comment: Like you could easily want matchers like "contains" or "is contained in" or sth similar

Comment: `def m: Matcher[String] = (s: String) => (isOk(s), s+ " is not ok")`

Comment: do you know how I could write a matcher that also takes right hand side parameter? In particular I am interested to write a matcher that checks whether left hand side string contains right hand side string: `"some string" should containString "me st"` @Eric

Comment: Yes, use a parameter: `def containString(expected: String): Matcher[String] = { actual: String => (actual.contains(expected), "wrong") }`.

Comment: The above did not work, but with slight modification, the following worked: `def containString(right: String): Matcher[String] = new Matcher[String] {
    def apply(left: String) = MatchResult(left.contains(right), s"'$left' does not contain '$right'", s"'$left' contains '$right'")
  }`

Comment: The version I gave you should work if you import `org.specs2.matcher.MatcherImplicits._` when you are outside a specification.

Answer (score 7):

I would like to add that you should be wary of **default arguments**, i.e. if using matchers when stubbing methods, make sure to pass argument matchers for *all* arguments, because default arguments will almost certainly have constant values - causing this same error to appear.

E.g. to stub the method

```
def myMethod(arg1: String, arg2: String arg3: String = "default"): String
```

you cannot simply do

```
def myMethod(anyString, anyString) returns "some value"
```

but you also need to pass an argument matcher for the default value, like so:

```
def myMethod(anyString, anyString, anyString) returns "some value"
```

Just lost half an hour figuring this out :)

Comment: This should be mentioned in the chosen answer, it just saved me a lot of time and frustration.