# InvalidUseOfMatchersException when I am passing any string for my mock parameter

Tags: scala, mockito

I want my mock to be able to handle any input for the method

```
val redis = mock[RedisClient]
when(redis.scard(any[String])).thenReturn(Some("hello"))
```

The error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: Invalid use of argument matchers!
[info] 2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
[info] -> at ..(SomeSpec.scala:123)
[info] 
[info] This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
[info]     //incorrect:
[info]     someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scard` takes two parameters, of which [one parameter](https://github.com/debasishg/scala-redis/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/redis/SetOperations.scala#L29) is [implicit](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/implicit-parameters.html):

```
// SCARD
// Return the number of elements (the cardinality) of the Set at key.
def scard(key: Any)(implicit format: Format): Option[Long] =
  send("SCARD", List(key))(asLong)
```

If you don't specify the argument, Scala will provide one, which interferes with Mockito's ability to [line up matchers with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891).

See also: [org.specs2.mock.Mockito matchers are not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32441824/1426891)